# Having trouble conceptualizing two Assembly programs

Tags: assembly

the two following programs were questions on a test that I took a few weeks ago, but I didn't get full credit for. I can't really figure out how to do them in any other way. I don't have the original code for them, but I was wondering if you guys/girls could show me examples of how you would have done it so that I can better prepared for our next test. If you could explain how your program works it would be greatly appreciated as well. Thank you!

1.) Write the a program to output your name 10 times, each time moving it in a downward diagonal direction, left to write. Use a loop.

Bob

(space)Bob

(space)(space)Bob

I tried to solve this one by adding in spaces before the string was printed each time adding in more spaces.

2.) Input 5 numbers, one at a tie int an array. Print the highest value entered and when it was entered.

This one I actually did pretty well on, I just could figure out how to display when it was entered.

Again thank you for any help you can provide. I tried looking around and couldn't find ASM questions that matched these well.

Edit: Using x86 processors and MASM. Our class book follows this,http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2012/index.htm#tutorial32.

Comment: An assembly answer is rather specific to a processor and perhaps an operating system.  Are you just after a sketch of how to lay it out, or real working code?

Comment: @JCx I'm sorry should have been more specific. Its with x86 processors and MASM. The book we are using follows this if that helps.http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2012/index.htm#tutorial32. and either would be fine, I just want to know how to do these problems better in case our next test uses something similar.

Comment: @JCx I'm sorry could you go into further detail. We didn't learn anything like that in this class.

Comment: Without code no one can tell you how to make it better (or nicer). With code http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be the better place.

Comment: @rkhb I wasn't asking anyone how to do it better, just how they would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answers for your two test-questions.

Next is the code for your program #1, the algorithm is like follows:

```
scounter = 1;
for ( ncounter = 10; ncounter > 0; ncounter-- )
{ for ( cx = scounter; cx > 0; cx-- )
     printf( ' ' );
  scounter++;         // ANOTHER BLANK SPACE. STRING WILL MOVE TO THE RIGHT.
  printf( 'Bob Wrath' );
  printf( '\n' );
}
```

It's simple: two counters, one for names, another for spaces. The names-counter is a reverse counter (decreases), the spaces-counter is normal (increases). Now the algorithm in assembly, made with EMU8086 but it's almost the same code for MASM (just change '$' by 0 and DB by BYTE). I used comments as titles for the little blocks of code to make them understandable :

```
.stack 100h

.data

myname   DB 'Bob Wrath$'
space    DB ' $'        ;BLANK SPACE.
break    DB 13,10,'$'   ;LINE BREAK.
ncounter DW ?           ;COUNTER FOR NAMES.
scounter DW ?           ;COUNTER FOR SPACES.

.code

;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;INITIALIZE COUNTERS.  
  mov  ncounter, 10     ;DISPLAY 10 NAMES.
  mov  scounter, 1      ;START WITH 1 SPACE TO THE LEFT.

names:

;DISPLAY SPACES BEFORE THE STRING.
  mov  cx, scounter     ;NUMBER OF SPACES TO DISPLAY.
spaces:
  mov  dx, offset space
  call printf      
  loop spaces           ;CX-1. IF CX > 0 JUMP TO SPACES.
;INCREASE SPACES-COUNTER FOR THE NEXT ROUND.
  inc  scounter         

;DISPLAY NAME.             
  mov  dx, offset myname
  call printf

;DISPLAY LINE BREAK.              
  mov  dx, offset break
  call printf           ;DISPLAY LINE BREAK.

;CHECK IF NAMES-COUNTER IS 0.
  dec  ncounter         ;NCOUNTER - 1.
  jnz  names            ;IF (NCOUNTER != 0) JUMP TO NAMES.  

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

;-----------------------------------------
;PARAMETER : DX POINTING TO '$' FINISHED STRING.
proc printf
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
endp
```

Now program #2. Again, I'm using EMU8086, that's why I used some procedures that might be unnecessary for MASM (string2number, dollars, number2string). The algorithm is very easy: capture 5 (or as many as you want) numbers from keyboard, every captured number is compared with the highest value (**very important** : the first highest value is 0, this is necessary to find the highest, to find the lowest the first value should be a very high number, like 32767, get it?, this way, the first entered number will be higher), finally, it displays the highest number. Notice I'm not using an array because it was unnecessary, the explained algorithm let us find the highest number without the help of an array:

```
.stack 100h

.data

counter dw ?

msj1    db 'Enter a number: $'
msj2    db 'The highest number is: $'
break   db 13,10,'$'

str     db 6                ;MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ALLOWED (5).
        db ?                ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER.
        db 6 dup (?)        ;CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER. 

highest dw 0        

buffer  db 6 dup(?)

.code

;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;-----------------------------------------
;CAPTURE 5 NUMBERS AND DETERMINE THE HIGHEST.

  mov  counter, 5           ;HOW MANY NUMBERS TO CAPTURE.
enter_numbers:                          

;DISPLAY MESSAGE.
  mov  dx, offset msj1
  call printf

;CAPTURE NUMBER AS STRING.
  mov  dx, offset str
  call scanf

;DISPLAY LINE BREAK.
  mov  dx, offset break
  call printf

;CONVERT CAPTURED NUMBER FROM STRING TO NUMERIC.
  mov  si, offset str       ;PARAMETER (STRING TO CONVERT).
  call string2number        ;NUMBER RETURNS IN BX.

;CHECK IF CAPTURED NUMBER IS THE HIGHEST.
  cmp  highest, bx  
  jae  ignore               ;IF (HIGHEST >= BX) IGNORE NUMBER.
;IF NO JUMP TO "IGNORE", CURRENT NUMBER IS HIGHER THAN "HIGHEST".  
  mov  highest, bx          ;CURRENT NUMBER IS THE HIGHEST.

ignore:  
;CHECK IF WE HAVE CAPTURED 5 NUMBERS ALREADY.
  dec  counter
  jnz  enter_numbers

;-----------------------------------------
;DISPLAY HIGHEST NUMBER.

;FIRST, FILL BUFFER WITH '$' (NECESSARY TO DISPLAY).
  mov  si, offset buffer
  call dollars

;SECOND, CONVERT HIGHEST NUMBER TO STRING.              
  mov  ax, highest
  mov  si, offset buffer
  call number2string

;THIRD, DISPLAY STRING.
  mov  dx, offset msj2
  call printf
  mov  dx, offset buffer
  call printf    

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

;-----------------------------------------
;PARAMETER : DX POINTING TO '$' FINISHED STRING.
proc printf
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
endp    

;-----------------------------------------
;PARAMETER : DX POINTING TO BUFFER TO STORE STRING.
proc scanf
  mov  ah, 0Ah
  int  21h
  ret
endp    

;------------------------------------------
;CONVERT STRING TO NUMBER.
;PARAMETER : SI POINTING TO CAPTURED STRING.
;RETURN    : NUMBER IN BX.

proc string2number
;MAKE SI TO POINT TO THE LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT.
  inc  si ;POINTS TO THE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.
  mov  cl, [ si ] ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.                                         
  mov  ch, 0 ;CLEAR CH, NOW CX==CL.
  add  si, cx ;NOW SI POINTS TO LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT.
;CONVERT STRING.
  mov  bx, 0
  mov  bp, 1 ;MULTIPLE OF 10 TO MULTIPLY EVERY DIGIT.
repeat:         
;CONVERT CHARACTER.                    
  mov  al, [ si ] ;CHARACTER TO PROCESS.
  sub  al, 48 ;CONVERT ASCII CHARACTER TO DIGIT.
  mov  ah, 0 ;CLEAR AH, NOW AX==AL.
  mul  bp ;AX*BP = DX:AX.
  add  bx, ax ;ADD RESULT TO BX. 
;INCREASE MULTIPLE OF 10 (1, 10, 100...).
  mov  ax, bp
  mov  bp, 10
  mul  bp ;AX*10 = DX:AX.
  mov  bp, ax ;NEW MULTIPLE OF 10.  
;CHECK IF WE HAVE FINISHED.
  dec  si ;NEXT DIGIT TO PROCESS.
  loop repeat ;COUNTER CX-1, IF NOT ZERO, REPEAT.

  ret 
endp    

;------------------------------------------
;FILLS VARIABLE WITH '$'.
;USED BEFORE CONVERT NUMBERS TO STRING, BECAUSE
;THE STRING WILL BE DISPLAYED.
;PARAMETER : SI = POINTING TO STRING TO FILL.

proc dollars                 
  mov  cx, 6
six_dollars:      
  mov  bl, '$'
  mov  [ si ], bl
  inc  si
  loop six_dollars

  ret
endp  

;------------------------------------------
;CONVERT A NUMBER IN STRING.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING (STR).
;PARAMETERS : AX = NUMBER TO CONVERT.
;             SI = POINTING WHERE TO STORE STRING.

proc number2string
  mov  bx, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
endp
```

Hope this helps you for your next test.